# Can I swap out the library used by a binary with a wrapper when building a third-party crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Let's say there is a vendored third-party cargo project consisting of a library `plem` and a binary `plem_main` that I want to extend with some functionality of my own. Crucially, the functionality needs to go in the library `plem`, not the binary `plem_main` (which can stay the same). I could write a wrapper `my_plem` around the library that offers the same interface to the binary, but with the extra functionality included. The project would be set up like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── my_plem
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
└── third-party
    ├── plem
    │   ├── Cargo.toml
    │   └── src
    │       └── lib.rs
    └── plem_main
        ├── Cargo.toml
        └── src
            └── main.rs
```

`my_plem/src/lib.rs` would depend on things in `third-party/plem/src/lib.rs` and reexport or overwrite the functions exported by the latter. Is there a good way to get cargo to build the binary `plem_main` on top of `my_plem` instead of `plem`?

"Best" here means that the solution has no or minimal merge conflicts when updating `plem` in my project and doesn't duplicate the code of `plem_main`. Ideally it does not touch third-party at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Does the [`patch` section of `Cargo.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-patch-section) solve your problem?

Comment: It's a good start, but fails when I try to define a lib with the same name as the original one. I'll look into it some more.

Comment: Edited the question. @SvenMarnach, patch should work, except it doesn't accept local paths, only an URL or a registry name. And I don't think I can build the plem_main binary directly from an URL, can I?

Comment: You should be able to use a local path in the patch section – see the example `bar = { path = 'my/local/bar' }` in the linked documentation.

Comment: I meant it doesn't let you write `[patch.'my/local/bar'] etc.`, i.e. when specifying the thing-to-replace, not the thing-with-which-to-replace.

Comment: I see. Honestly, I've got no idea whether this is possible with `patch`. You could also try `replace` instead.